# how to pass a more @Model parameters to the same razorengine template

Tags: asp.net, razor

for example the A.razortemplate

```
<html>
<title>@Page.Title</title>
<keywords>@Page.Title</keywords>
<body>
    crumb:<a href="">@Page.Title</a>><a href="">@Post.Title</a>
    <h3>@Post.Title<h3>
    @Post.Body
    by-@User.PostAuthor
</body>
</html>
```

the above code in the one template(A),it include three @Model object that @Page,@Post,@User.i read the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) code,find just can pass one @Model patameter to the template,the following code from RazorEngine project.

```
protected virtual ITemplate CreateTemplate<T>(Type templateType, T model)
{
    var instance = CreateTemplate(templateType);
    SetModel(instance, model);
    return instance;
}
```

i hated only just can pass one @Model,i need to some more flexible method,i can remove crumb statement from template at anytime,can add time of the post.

for the above problem,may be i can create a new class and create three propertys for @page,@post,@user,i think it not perfect solution.

by the way,i want to take the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) as the front-end template(like a string template etc.),the ASP.NET as back-end just do sql operation and pass data to front-end.someone can give some suggest?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RazorEngine uses a singular `Model` property be default. This property can be any type you like, so why not create a composite model:

```
public class TemplateModel
{
    public PostModel Post { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
    public PageModel Page { get; set; }
}
```

That way you can pass a singular model, and access the properties as:

```
@Model.User.PostAuthor
```